# D3 - Reading from .json and attempting to plot points - nothing displayed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been following various tutorials from over the past few years (seems D3 has gone through a bunch of changes) but cannot seem to nail this basic task down. Loading data in from MonthySales.json and trying to plot the points. Blank screen, but no errors at all in console.

```
    var h=100;
    var w=400;
    
    d3.json("MonthlySales.json", function(error, data) { 

        var dataset = data
    
        var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {return ((d.month-20130001)/3.25)})
        .y(function (d) {return h-d.sales; })
    
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h)
    
        svg.append("path").datum(dataset).attr("class","line").attr("d",line)
           .attr("fill","none").attr("stroke","purple").attr("stroke-width","2")

        });
```

JSON is set up in the form:

```
[
{"month":20130101, "sales":38},
{"month":20130201, "sales":35},
{"month":20130301, "sales":24},
{"month":20130401, "sales":21},
{"month":20130501, "sales":34},
{"month":20130601, "sales":45},
{"month":20130701, "sales":67},
{"month":20130801, "sales":1},
{"month":20130901, "sales":54},
{"month":20131001, "sales":10},
{"month":20131101, "sales":20},
{"month":20131201, "sales":30}
]
```

Comment: `d3.select("Body")` should be `d3.select("body")`

Comment: Hi Andrew - thanks for finding that. Fixed, but still the same result of nothing displaying or no errors.

Comment: It displayed fine for me when I revised that - but what version of d3 are you using?

Comment: v6 here: <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: `d3.json("MonthlySales.json", function(error, data) { ` should be `d3.json("MonthlySales.json").then(function(data) {` as of d3v5

Comment: beauty - worked like a charm. Thanks, Andrew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On V5/v6 *[d3.json()](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/src/json.js)* is a wrapper of *JS fetch*, and *fetch* is a promise.

```
function responseJson(response) {
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
  if (response.status === 204 || response.status === 205) return;
  return response.json();
}

export default function(input, init) {
  return fetch(input, init).then(responseJson);
}
```

*input* argument remains a the route to the JSON, but *init* is the options object of *fetch()*

```
{
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  }
```

*responseJson()* process the response of the promise and pass a JSON Object to the next *then()*

Now the correct way to do this is

```js
const h = 100;
const w = 400;

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jkutianski/57d1d392068b6c5a9216466f9e5d6459/raw/f93d5c296c3b6b69c920c573e010a29cc4339f2a/MonthlySales.json")
  .then(dataset => {
    const line = d3.line()
      .x(d => (d.month - 20130001) / 3.25)
      .y(d => h - d.sales);

    const svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(dataset)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "purple")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
</body>
</html>
```